# Get instance of Excel application with C# by Handle

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I have a c# simple application that have to write some values in a excel ranges of a specific worksheet.
I create an instance of Excel application if not exist, but if exist i want to set active it and take an instance if it to use in my code.

I use this code to create a new application:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel app = 
   new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
app.Visible = true;
```

To get the handle of active excel window i use this api

```
[DllImportAttribute("User32.dll")]
private static extern int FindWindow(String ClassName, String WindowName);
```

How can i get an instance of excel application by an handle?

```
int hWnd = FindWindow(null, "Microsoft Excel - MySheet.xlsx");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel app = ....(hWnd)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the following code to get the first running instance of Excel:

```
oExcelApp =  (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
```

**Example**

```
public Excel.Application StartExcel()
{
    Excel.Application instance = null;
    try
    {
       instance = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
    }
    catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
    {
       instance = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
    }

    return instance;
}
```

Comment: For me, `instance = new Excel.ApplicationClass();` didn't work. I had to use `instance = new Excel.Application();`.

Comment: @DavidMurdoch this is the result of a [change in VS2010 for embedding interop types](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mshneer/archive/2009/12/07/interop-type-xxx-cannot-be-embedded-use-the-applicable-interface-instead.aspx). Switching to `Application()` over `ApplicationClass()` is a workaround, you get the same result (even though it looks like you are instantiating an interface!).

Answer (score 15):

There might be more than one Excel instance running.

GetActiveObject(...) looks in the Running Object Table (ROT) and would give you the last Excel instance that was opened - not necessarily the one corresponding with the window handle you have.

You're looking for AccessibleObjectFromWindow(..). The [Andrew Whitechapel post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2008/11/30/starting-or-connecting-to-office-apps.aspx) linked to in the other answer shows how to use this function.

Another link - http://blogs.officezealot.com/whitechapel/archive/2005/04/10/4514.aspx.

Comment: The links are broken.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Marshal.GetActiveObject, see this blog post for details:

http://blogs.msdn.com/andreww/archive/2008/11/30/starting-or-connecting-to-office-apps.aspx