# Excel Worksheet Modifying Current Sheet C#

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

Is there anyway that you can modify an already opened worksheet in Excel. Their MSDN page gives you what is below. This adds a new workbook and worksheet everytime. I have the code opening and existing worksheet, and I just want it to replace the value in the cell and the close. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; //Excel Reference

 public virtual Object ActiveSheet { get; set; }

 private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Generate Model and Part Numbers
    {
        Excel.Application oXL;
        Excel._Workbook oWB;
        Excel._Worksheet oSheet;

        //Start Excel and get Application object.
        oXL = new Excel.Application();
        oXL.Visible = true;

        //Get a new workbook.
        oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value));
        oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;  
        oSheet.Cells[6, 4] = "0"; //Change Value in Cell in Excel Cell Location [y-axis, x-axis]
     }
```

Comment: I called Microsoft and they were going to charge me 500 bucks for this answer so anyone who gets this praise to you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can iterate over `oXL.Workbooks` to access the currently open Workbooks... the currently active Workbook is available via [`oXl.ActiveWorkbook`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.activeworkbook.aspx).

EDIT - as per comment:

Either use `oXL.Windows` to find the already open window and call `Activate` on that before  before accessing `ActiveWorkbook` or just call `oXL.ActiveWindow.Close()` or `oXL.ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious()` to get the already open window...

EDIT 2 - as per comment final part of solution:

use

```
oXL = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
```

Comment: Yeah I guess I can't figure it out there is no Object ActiveWorkbook at least not one that I could find

Comment: see my updated answer and the link - there is `oXl.ActiveWorkbook` !

Comment: what is oXL = then it can't be new Excel.Application that will open another excel window and error out. Is there anything else I can make oXL equal to

Comment: oXL is the new Excel application - since Excel won't be started a second time ("Singleton") everything is fine...

Comment: I am not sure why but when I run that code it opens a new excel window other then the one already opened and errors

Comment: then use `oXL.Windows` to find the already open window and call `Activate` on that that before  before accessing `ActiveWorkbook`. or just call `oXL.ActiveWindow.Close()` or `oXL.ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious()`...

Comment: hmm no go again same NullReferenceException

Comment: combine that with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118735/get-instance-of-excel-application-with-c-by-handle - if this does not work then is something really strange with you OS/Excel installation... are you by any chance trying to do this from a Windows Service OR a second "desktop session" or or ?

Comment: Got it I figured it out I can't post the answer due to stack overflow

Comment: glad that you solved it :-) please don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted any answer that was of help.

Comment: Will do I will post when I can

Comment: oXL = (Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"); That is how i solved the whole fiasco

Comment: that is exactly what is behind the link I put in my comment above... glad that this solved it :-)

Comment: you are welcom - I added the solution as "EDIT 2" for reference.

Comment: This will help tons of people I found so many forums on this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I came up with I hope this will help everyone out. Thanks for everyone who helped

```
 using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; //Excel Reference   

  public virtual Object ActiveSheet { get; set; }   

  private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Generate Model and Part Numbers   
  {   
        //Gets ActiveSheet to Modify
        Excel.Application oXL;
        Excel.Workbook oWB;
        Excel.Worksheet oSheet;

        //Start Excel and get Active Workbook and Sheet to modify
        oXL = (Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"); 
        oXL.Visible = true;
        oWB = (Excel.Workbook)oXL.ActiveWorkbook; 
        oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;   

        //Cell Input
        oSheet.Cells[6, 4] = "0"; //Change Value in Cell in Excel Cell Location [y-axis, x-axis] 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you open like below then you will create just a new instance. 
 oXL = new Excel.Application();

c# will create a second excel process. With this way you can not access to any Excel application, which one opened by the user manually.

If you want to open active worksheet which one is opened not by your application then please check here:
[Get instance of Excel application with C# by Handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118735/get-instance-of-excel-application-with-c-by-handle)

all the rest is same:

```
oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
```

if you want to have access to worksheet, which you open via c# instance then:(.net framework 4)

```
using Excel;

    Excel.Application oXl = new Excel.Application();
    Workbook oWb = oxl.workbooks.add();
    Worksheet oWs = oWs.Worksheets(1); //As default excel will open 3 worksheet and active worksheet will be first one.
```

Edit: I didnt check the code block can be typing error.

Comment: This also opens the a new application, but does not modify an existing opened file

Comment: Got it thanks for the help. I can't post the answer due to StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

Might be simpler to abandon the Interop Classes and use OLEDB to run an update query on the sheet.  I can provide examples if your interested.

Comment: I got it thanks for the help can't post due to stack overflow