# How to take control of the currently running instance of PowerPoint, by process id?

Tags: .net, powerpoint

Another program, outside my own program, creates a new PowerPoint presentation.  When it does, my program can detect the process ID of the PowerPoint presentation.

I want to take control of the currently running instance of PowerPoint so that I can copy slides or at least save the presentation. How would I do this in .NET?

Comment: a powerpoint presentation is a file, not a process.

Comment: @DanielA.White: Thanks for the clarification.  I meant that I want to take control of the current running instance of PowerPoint. How can this be done?

Comment: @Daniel unless the powerpoint is run, or unless the powerpoint is converted to a standalone executable. Though I doubt that's what's meant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

powerpoint offers a large automation [api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff746842.aspx) utilizable though .net.

Comment: I concur. Working with any MS Office application can best be done through the large and mature API, as opposed to hacking your way in through low level system calls.

Comment: I agree that the API is a better way of automating Office apps, but in this situation, the PowerPoint application is started by Minitab which also creates the presentation and populates the slides.  I am trying to automate the process of extracting the slides from this presentation and copying them into another presentation.

Comment: @blueshift Have you tried it with the office interop API? I'm not sure but you may be able to attach to a running instance of PP. In fact I'd be surprised if it's not possible.

Comment: I found the answer in another SO post: [so]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118735/get-instance-of-excel-application-with-c-sharp-by-handle