# Load an Excel file using implicit typing

Tags: c#, file-io, global-variables

```
class ExcelHandling
    {
        public static void NewExcelFile(){
            frmMain._frmMain.EXCEL_FILE = new Excel.Application();
            var excelApp = frmMain._frmMain.EXCEL_FILE as Excel.Application;
            excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
            excelApp.Visible = true;
        }

        public static void LoadExcelFile()
        {
            FileStream load = File.Open(@"F:\dsa.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write);
            var excelApp = load as Excel.Application;
            frmMain._frmMain.EXCEL_FILE = excelApp;
            excelApp.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

The above shown `LoadExcelFile()` method doesn't work.

What is the correct way of loading an existing excel file into a variable? I've tried a few things, but to no avail. The `NewExcelFile()` method works like a charm - it creates a new Excel file, stores it into the EXCEL_FILE global variable so I can manipulate it thereafter and shows it. I want the load function to do the same but with an existing excel file.

Comment: I would look into [Excel Data Reader](https://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/) - It's lightweight and very easy to use.  Loads your data into a `DataSet`, then you can maniuplate it easily.

Comment: Maybe check out this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118735/get-instance-of-excel-application-with-c-sharp-by-handle

Comment: @Kapol I'm planning on making a load file dialog so getting an already running excel file won't do it for me. I just need to open the file, so It's visible to the user and load it into the variable so he can manipulate it through the windows form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of opening an existing Excel spreadsheet using the Microsoft.Interop library:

```
var xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
var xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("PathAndNameOfMyFile.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true,    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
```

The overload parameters are fairly vague in documentation, but unfortunately required.  Intellisense should give you some idea of the values and their meaning.

Your issue was that you were using a `FileStream` and then trying to let the library figure out what that stream contained.  This will utilize the interop library to open the file and handle the data properly.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for, I guess I should check out the MS.Interop library a bit more thoroughly.

Comment: Ha no problem.  Some of the stuff in there has really bad documentation so you have to look in intelli-sense half the time.

Answer (score 0):

I really like LinqToExcel.  You can use NuGet Package Mgr in Visual Studio to add it https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqToExcel .  Documentation is @https://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/ (with a demo video)

Comment: I would prefer not to add an external library for just this one operation. If possible I'd like to convert the file stream into an excel application variable using the default c# libraries.

Comment: Oh.  Have you tried excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"F:\dsa.xlsx")?

Comment: Here is the method documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open.aspx