# Method 'Display Alerts' of object '_Application Failed' error

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a function "TestFunction" in an excel file, the function has line 
`"Application.DisplayAlerts = False"` in it, problem is if i manually run this function it doesn't thorw any error, error `"Method 'Display Alerts' of object '_Application Failed' error"` throws when I call the function from middle tier(C#) to execute it.

I dont know what to check here.

Please somebody reply.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely the solution is to bind excel application first to an object. As if called from C#, the call `Application.DisplayAlerts` doesn't refer to anything. I'm not quite sure how to do this in C# but in VBA you do this by doing something like `Dim XL as Object` and after `Set XL = createObject(Class:="Excel.Application")` and then use `XL.DisplayAlerts = False` ..

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is somehow related to MS Internet Explorer (full article [here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;165435)). In your question you don't specify anything about how or from where you're calling your macro, so I can't be sure. However, I've seen instances like this where the code is referring to the MSIE `Application` object and not the Excel one. Even if it's not MSIE, it could still be another object that has its own `Application` defined so it conflicts with Excel's `Application` object, so the following should still apply.

If I'm right, then you need to add the following line of code to your macro **before** the line of code that changes the `DisplayAlerts` property:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

You can also add the following line of code **after** the line of code that changes the `DisplayAlerts` property:

```
On Error GoTo 0
```

So basically, something like this:

```
On Error Resume Next 'This line is required.
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error GoTo 0      'This line is optional to revert the error handling to default behaviour.
```

By adding these lines of code to your macro, you suppress the error message and the macro continues to run. Note that you cannot change the `DisplayAlerts` property in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I dont understand your answer, if "Note that you cannot change the DisplayAlerts property in this case." is the case then why I`ve to add "Application.DisplayAlerts = False".

Comment: @user3842389: The reason you cannot change the `DisplayAlerts` property is because you don't have access to Excel's `Application` object -- the name has been "hijacked" by MSIE or whatever. You can either have the `DisplayAlerts` line with disabled error reporting or you can remove it altogether. If you want to execute your script from Excel sometimes (and not always through C#), then it's worth leaving the line in, up to you. My suggestion should fix the issue you're having though. Am I right that MSIE is involved here?

Comment: Yeah MSIE is involved, but even if i avoid using MSIE,as i know other ways to check, then also it threw same error.

Comment: @user3842389: It's hard for me to know exactly what your code is doing in all cases where you call it, I even had to make a (correct, as it turned out) guess about MSIE being involved. C# has its own `Application` object in `System.Windows` (and also `System.Windows.Forms`), so I'm assuming that's the object your code is looking at and not the `Excel.Application` object.

Comment: @user3842389: This article might help: [How to: Access Office Interop Objects by Using Visual C# 2010 Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd264733(v=vs.110).aspx). Also, this SO question: [Get instance of Excel application with C# by Handle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118735/get-instance-of-excel-application-with-c-sharp-by-handle) might enable you to access the `Excel.Application` object from your C# code.