# Powershell: how to reference to a specific Excel application if more than one Excel application are open

Tags: excel, powershell, runtime

Suppose I type a code like this:

```
$excel = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
```

It will only work if I only have one Excel application open.  If I have two Excel applications open, `$excel` might reference to the wrong one.  Is there a way to reference to a specific Excel application, for example, based on its filename or its window title?

Comment: First find the window (by title?), grab the handle, then get Excel: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1118822/736079

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
$sig = @"
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);
"@
Add-Type -MemberDefinition $sig -Namespace User32 -Name Util -UsingNamespace System.Text
$p=0
[User32.util]::GetWindowThreadProcessId($MSExcel.HWND, [ref]$p) |out-null
Get-Process -id $p | Stop-Process
```

To be honest I don't remember where I got it (I sure didn't write it), but it's worked for my needs to be able to end the Excel window that my script specifically launched.